# How to make Excel.Application.InputBox display and get focus

Tags: c#, excel, inputbox

My AddIn uses C#, in order to reference cells in Excel, I use 
`Excel.Application.InputBox`, it works.

However, the `InputBox` always hides behind and every time I have to click to bring it to front which is annoying. Just wonder how to make it display in front?

Edit 
There is no such method like BringtoFront

The signature of the method is

```
public object InputBox(string prompt, object title, object _default, object left, object top, object helpFile, object helpContextID, object type)
```

Comment: is there a BringToFront property or something like that ..? have you looks at MSDN

Comment: use the FindWindow method to get the handle then apply focus. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx  and BringWindowToTop method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673(v=vs.85).aspx